# Is there any way to "vote" for an answer to be in the community wiki?

Tags: discussion

[Why are there two types of adjectives?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/1008/769) thread had a really good answer. I thought it should be in the community wiki. However, I did not see anyway to vote or even put it in the community wiki. It could be I don't have the rights to do so. So in short, is there a way to mark an answer as a candidate for the community wiki?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hmm... I think you're a bit confused about what "community wiki" is.

The community wiki posts are usually used for cases where you know the answer you are giving is incomplete or is going to need editing from other users. It suppresses the normal upvote/downvote credit system, since it's expected that many users will be contributing to the answer, so it would be unfair to credit a single person.

[Requisite Meta-StackOverflow Link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts)

---

EDIT: Troyen pointed out the canonical ["what is community-wiki" blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/the-future-of-community-wiki/) to me in chat.

---

What I think you're looking for is a more along the lines of a vote for a "featured question", similar to the Community Bulletin thing from meta we have up there now. I'm not actually certain if there is such a thing. (or if CB can be used that way)

Comment: If a user marks a question as a favorite one, then that will show up to other users. If more users do that, the that number will show up. Perhaps that can have a similar function as marking featured questions.

Comment: Alternatively, close a bunch of questions as duplicates of that question and it will eventually show up in the questions->faq tab. ;)

Answer (score 4):

There isn't a way to vote to make someone's post Community Wiki, and it's been stated on Meta Stack Overflow that it won't be implemented. But if you believe that an answer should be made Community Wiki, you can flag it for moderator attention.

Community Wiki only really does the following however:

- Makes it so that posts are editable for people who have only 100 reputation (although people who have less than the [1000 reputation needed to edit posts](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/privileges/edit) can still suggest edits which a JLU user with [1500 or higher reputation can approve](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/privileges/approve-tag-wiki-edits)), and
- Makes it so that the original author won't gain any more reputation.

I can't see other people doing lots of edits on this answer, so I don't think it would have much of an advantage in this case.

**Reference:** [Should the community wiki police be shut down?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/392/should-the-community-wiki-police-be-shut-down).